# How should I compare headphones?

Tags: audio, headphones

I'm finding difficulty in selecting one of these products and I thought you guys could help me better finding the best out of these four headphones .

http://www.flipkart.com/headphones/compare?ids=ACCD55RCHQKQFCYU,ACCCYGKQED6YC86G,ACCDD3J2USV9QY26,ACCD99E7FFVD2ZXH

**Does more impedance mean less volume ?**

**Does the lower frequency range mean more bass ?**

Comment: Hi Mevin - welcome to the site. I have edited your question to focus on the technical aspects, as shopping recommendations are off topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does more impedance mean less volume ?

As to impedance, take a look at Bill Griddle's answer:
https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/650/what-is-the-effect-of-impedance-on-headphone-sound-quality

In *essence*: yes, higher impedance = lower volume. But higher volume is not necessarily better quality. Most professional headphones has a high impedance. Are you A DJ then low impedance is more important to be able to hear the cue at all when performing.

> Does the lower frequency range mean more bass ?

Not necessarily. It only means that the headphones are capable of reproducing the frequencies (and details) in this area - if they exist. Most commercial productions are mastered with a cut-off in the lower range between 50/60-80 Hz (depends of course) to allow more room for other frequencies as well as remove "muffle-ness".

In the other end, a grown-up person's ears have typically had damages over the years and is not capable of hearing the highest frequencies above 15-16kHz - and most music rarely contain frequencies in this area or above (unless they want to torture the listener).

But typically the frequency range says something about the general quality - the lower the the lowest frequency is and the higher the highest frequency is, the better range can re-produced with these headphones - it's a good thing

But you can still have factors such as EQ bias towards a certain EQ color. The better the headphones are the more neutral EQ color it has IMO.

Update: to identify if the headphones have a preferable bias, lets say you want them to re-produce bass louder, you can read the frequency response diagram. An example [from this page](http://www.headphone.com/headphones/akg-k-550.php):

[image: example of frequency response diagram]

Here you can see it increases the frequency at around 40-50 Hz, 1 kHz and at around 8 kHz as well as 11 kHz. This means you will probably experience more bass and treble with these headphones then there is in the original track. Without a diagram like this the only way to find out is to have them on the head.

In the end it is coming down to personal preference - if they sound good to you with the sound/music you listen to, there is nothing wrong of picking them.

Personally I ended up with Beyerdynamic DT990. AKG was always a favorite as well as Sennheiser.

Comment: So is there anyway to identify which headphones might have more bass by looking into the values ?

Comment: Not without a frequency response curve to show the bias (see f.ex. here: http://www.headphone.com/headphones/akg-k-550.php). The best thing is of course to test them directly or check what others say about the bass to get a pointer.